# Uploading entities to azure storage table from XML file through powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-table-storage

I had been looking for the answer since long time. Still, no satisfactory answer found.

I have my data in a plain XML file which I want to upload to an azure storage table. I can easily do it through C# code, but due to some restrictions I need to do it through power shell script only. Has anybody done something similar.

Comment: Why not simply compile your C# code into an .exe file and use it from powershell?

Comment: Due to some organizational restrictions *.exe files are not acceptable as they have compiled code, while poweshell scripts are easily acceptable.

Comment: Please add proper comment/reason when down-voting a question. As a community member, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom fuctions as PowerShell modules.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/11/10/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-create-a-custom-function.aspx

It is also possible to add C# code to your PowerShell scripts:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts/